# Re-executing filters / methods

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Why the filter bar is re-executed when I press "increment button". If a property/data is modified, all filters will be re-executed? If yes, why I should use filters anymore?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-4ntlo

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: *If yes, why I should use filters anymore?* - why should you not use them? There's no problem, as long as they are light on resources.

Comment: If I have a filter `join` to concatenate elements of an array. This means, for every `data` update, a new array is created for no reason?